# change the database at run time codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, session

I have an App which uses multiple databases. I want to authenticate users from my parent database. Then save Session data in the the relevant database of the user.

Currently the session Library in CodeIgniter is saving Session data in default database. I want to change the database at run time so that i may save future data in the relevant database of the user.

Just let me know how can i set the database name in Session Lib

```
if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE)
    {
        $this->CI->db1->query($this->CI->db1->insert_string($this->sess_table_name, $this->userdata));
    }
```

I want to change $this->CI-db1 to be changed every time when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an custom core name **MY_Controller** and in **__construct()** method, you can add the follow code:

```
public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();


        $this->user = $this->load->database("default", true);
        $this->session = $this->load->database("session", true);


    }
```

When you need to add in session database, you call:

```
$this->session->insert()
```

This is what you need?

Comment: I want to authenticate the users from Parent Database. Then I want to store the session data in Child Database. For example if I have 3 databases for 3 different users then those users shall be authenticated from parent database. Then each user's session id and session data should be saved in their appropriate relevant databases.